# Mapping graphs to ordinals

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, ordinal-numbers

Robertson-Seymour theorem implies that graph minor relation is a well-quasi-ordering, which means (among other things) that this relation can be extended to a well-order, and other result says that this order can have order type $\psi(\Omega_\omega)$, if I remember correctly. I've been wondering - has anyone actually analysed this ordering? For example, in such ordering, what place would $K_{3,3}$ take? $K_5$? Petersen graph? Only such analysis I know of is on this page:

http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Hyp_cos/SCG(n)_and_some_related

but it only concerns subcubic graphs, because of their connection to SCG function.

Thanks in advance for any help!

(If you think this fits better to Math StackExchange, please move the question)

Comment: One potential problem is that there are many different ways that one may extend a well-quasi-order to a well-order, so it's not clear that "this ordering" is well-defined. On the other hand, given a well-quasi-ordering we do get a notion of rank, so we can ask what the rank of natural graphs in that wqo is. I don't know what has been done around here - I suspect there is a good deal known - but I would be very interested.